# Landscape mode takes portrait sized pictures in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, autorotate

When I start the application, it works fine.
But when I rotate it to `landscape` mode, the `UIButton` on the iPhone still takes `portrait` frame sized pictures.

```
  if (IS_IPHONE)
    {

        [Arrowbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"drop-down-icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
        {


            if(IS_IPHONE_5)
            {
                Arrowbutton.frame = CGRectMake(530.0, 15.0, 19.0, 23.0);
            }
            else
            {
              //
                Arrowbutton.frame = CGRectMake(260.0, 15.0, 19.0, 23.0);

            }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:Arrowbutton];

           }
           else
            {
                Arrowbutton.frame = CGRectMake(260.0, 15.0, 19.0, 23.0);
            }

        [cell.contentView addSubview:Arrowbutton];

    }
```

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: where you add this Arrowbtton ???????

Comment: Where do you use your code?

Comment: on cell right corner. @ParvendraSingh

Comment: cell forrowAtindecxPath @Szu

Comment: Reload your table in viewWillApper??????????

Comment: already i've done.@ParvendraSingh

Comment: first time it work fine but after rotating i take both cooradinate (landscape and potrait) in landscape mode. @ParvendraSingh

Comment: You code is right.....

Comment: Please call reloadData on tableView when after you rotate application.

Comment: If you are in portrait mode, you add button twice.  If cell is nil, you can add button with correct frame else just update rect. Don't forget to reload table on rotation as guys mentioned.